# Mercurial diff/patch by example

Tags: mercurial, diff

I have read only permission to an `hg` repo and am trying to develop and test changes to it locally. The problem is that I am in the middle of changing dev machines and am caught in a weird/akward state across the two machines.

On my old machine I made lots of changes to the repo, locslly. I just cloned the repo on my new machine, but obviously that doesn't contain the changes from my old machine. I need a way to createe a patch/diff from my local working copy on my old machine, and then apply them to my local working copy on my new machine. The problem is that I already commited (`hg commit -m "Blah"`) the changes on my old machine to the distributed repo on it.

What set of specific commands can I use to create a patch/diff of my old machine and then apply it to the repo on my new one?

---

#### Update

I commited all changes on my old machine and then ran `hg serve`, exposing `http://mymachine.example.com:8000`.

On my new machine, where I had made some different changes (locally) than the changes from my old machine, I ran `hg pull http://mymachine.example.com:8000` and got:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/sandbox/eclipse/workspace/myapp$ hg pull http://mymachine.example.com:8000
pulling from http://mymachine.example.com:8000/
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 2 changesets with 16 changes to 10 files (+1 heads)
(run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)
```

So I run `hg merge`:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/sandbox/eclipse/workspace/myapp$ hg merge
abort: uncommitted changes
(use 'hg status' to list changes)
```

**What do I do now?!?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$ hg diff > changes.patch
```

To create a patch file, then:

```
$ patch -p1 < changes.patch
```

To apply that patch file on your new machine.

Comment: Thanks @David Wolever (+1) - please see my update and comment underneath John Jeffries answer...I have the same question for you! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's actually fantastic, mercurial is a *distributed* version control system and you do not need to go via any patch file at all: simply pull the changes from your old machine to your new machine:

`hg pull URL`

where URL can be any network URL or also ssh-login, e.g.

`hg pull ssh://mylogin@old.maschine.box` or `hg pull path/to/old/repository/on/nfs/mount`
`

Alternatively you can also use `bundle` and `unbundle`. They create bundles which can be imported in the new mercurial easily and keep all meta-information.

`hg bundle -r XXX --base YYY > FILENAME`

where YYY is a revision you know you have in your new repository. You import it into your new repo with `hg unbundle FILENAME`. Of course you can bundle several changesets at once by repeating the -r argument or giving a changeset range like `-r X:Y`.

The least comfortable method is a via diff or export:

`hg export -r XXX > FILENAME` or equivalent `hg diff -c XXX > FILENAME` where you need to import the result with `patch -p1 < FILENAME` or `hg import FILENAME`.

Comment: Thanks @planetmaker (+1) - please see my update and comment underneath John Jeffries answer...I have the same question for you! Thanks again!

Comment: commit your local uncommitted changes and exercise the merge then. Just like the message tells you :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to do this is to ensure that all work on your old machine is committed. Then use this command on it from the base of your repo:

```
hg serve
```

which creates a simple http server on this repo. The monitor should state the name of the http URL it is serving.

On your new machine, just pull from that URL.

Once you've pulled your old changes you can stop the hg serve process with ^C.

The advantages of this method are that it is very quick, and that it works on just about any system. The ssh method is also quick, but it won't work unless your system is configured to use ssh.

**Answer to Update**
The OPs update is asking an orthogonal question about how to merge changes pulled from a server with local changes. If you haven't already done so, try to digest the information in [this merge doc](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialMerge) and [this one](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Merge).

Merging is for merging changesets. The error is happening because you have local changes that haven't been committed which mercurial can't merge. So the first thing to do is to commit your local changes, then you will be able to merge.

But before you merge, I strongly recommend that you are merging what you think you are merging. Either ensure there are only 2 heads, or specify which head you are merging with. When merging, you have to be at one of the heads you wish to merge; it's usually better to be at the head with the most changes since the common ancestor because the diffs are simpler.

After you've merged, don't forget to commit the merge. :-)

Comment: good point about `hg serve` for systems w/o ssh. I'm just not used to such systems anymore :)

Comment: Thanks @John Jeffries (+1) - please see my update...any ideas? Thanks again!